# Make absolute button have sticky animation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code:

https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/qBBOwyN

Snippet:

```
<div class="post-body d-flex">
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="post-content">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <!-- button toggle -->
    <button type="button" class="btn sticky1 border-white outline-none"  style="box-shadow:none;" id="toc-button">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wwWQ.png" width="25px" height="100px">
    </button>

    <!-- table of contents -->
    <div class="post-toc">
        <div class="d-block sticky-top mb-5">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class=" sticky-top btn outline-none" style="box-shadow:none" id="toc-button-2">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/s1ej0s3.png" height="20px" >
                </button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <nav class="" id="toc"></nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

My problem is that I can't make [toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wwWQ.png) become sticky with out changing the layout. I tried to change its position to sticky but the layout will change a little bit.

So I think best way is use a Jquery script to make it become sticky. In codepen, if you click on TOC button, it will expand a table of contents, and this table of contents has perfect sticky animation that I want.

Can you please help me to make a script to make my TOC button become sticky in it's father div .post-body?

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it sticky, then make absolute positioned wrapper with desired placement and height 100%: https://codepen.io/f278f1b2/pen/vYYNwpz?editors=1100#anon-signup

```
#toc-button {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 110px;
  position: sticky;
  /*margin-top: 30px;*/
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.toc-wrapper {
  right: 0;
  top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: OMG. Simple but perfect. You are genius. Thank you so much, sir.